# DataTables, how to have scroll-x bar to skip first column

Tags: javascript, css, datatables

I have this problem which is well described by the image
below. I need to have the scrollbar start from the second column
for aesthetical reasons. I have no idea how to achieve this, do you have 
any suggestion ? The first black column will contain icons, it is not
just a place holder.

[image]

Comment: I am aware of FixedColums but this page [link](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/) warns about the notable complexity it would introduce. So I prefer to avoid it. By now, I solved with an hack, I put a black DIV to cover the unwanted part of the slider. Then, a scroll listener adjust the size of the DIV when needed. If you have better solutions let me know !